# Can't create named map containing complex CSS condition using cURL

Tags: carto, cartocss

I'd like to style contour lines so that they show differently at varying levels of zoom.  When zoomed right out, only the 200m, 400m, 600m, etc. lines should show.  When zoomed in a bit further, the 100m, 300m, etc. lines should appear.  Text should appear too when zooming in.

I can achieve this fine using reasonably concise `OR` syntax in Builder, but when I try to cURL definitions containing `OR` conditions to create a named map, the map stops working.

For example, this one works both when cURLed *and* in Builder:

```
#layer[value='200'] {
    line-width: 0.7;
    line-color: #4b3ebc;
    line-opacity: 1;
}
```

But this one containing the `OR` condition `,[value='400']` only works in Builder: it does *not* work when cURLed:

```
#layer[value='200'],[value='400'] {
    line-width: 0.7;
    line-color: #4b3ebc;
    line-opacity: 1;
}
```

I can achieve the desired effect by cURLing this more verbose expression of the same thing, but would rather use more concise syntax because the full styling I need involves many more conditions:

```
#layer[value='200'] {
  line-width: 1.5;
  line-color: #4b3ebc;
  line-opacity: 1;
}

#layer[value='400'] {
  line-width: 1.5;
  line-color: #4b3ebc;
  line-opacity: 1;
}
```

For reference, here's the full styling I'm trying to achieve, expressed using concise syntax:

```
#layer[value='200'],[value='400'],[value='600'],[value='800'],[value='1000'],[value='1200'],[value='1400'],[value='1600'],[value='1800'],[value='2000'] {
  line-width: 1.5;
  line-color: #4b3ebc;
  line-opacity: 1;
}

#layer[zoom>10][value='200'],[zoom>10][value='400'],[zoom>10][value='600'],[zoom>10][value='800'],[zoom>10][value='1000'],[zoom>10][value='1200'],[zoom>10][value='1400'],[zoom>10][value='1600'],[zoom>10][value='1800'],[zoom>10][value='2000'] {
  text-face-name: 'DejaVu Sans Book';
  text-name: [value];
}

#layer[zoom>10][value='200'],[zoom>10][value='400'],[zoom>10][value='600'],[zoom>10][value='800'],[zoom>10][value='1000'],[zoom>10][value='1200'],[zoom>10][value='1400'],[zoom>10][value='1600'],[zoom>10][value='1800'],[zoom>10][value='2000'] {
  text-face-name: 'DejaVu Sans Book';
  text-name: [value];
}

#layer[zoom>11][value='100'],[zoom>11][value='300'],[zoom>11][value='500'],[zoom>11][value='700'],[zoom>11][value='900'],[zoom>11][value='1100'],[zoom>11][value='1300'],[zoom>11][value='1500'],[zoom>11][value='1700'],[zoom>11][value='1900'],[zoom>11][value='2100'] {
  line-width: 1.0;
  line-color: #4b3ebc;
  line-opacity: 1;
  text-face-name: 'DejaVu Sans Book';
  text-name: [value];
}

#layer[zoom>12][value='50'],[zoom>12][value='150'],[zoom>12][value='250'],[zoom>12][value='350'],[zoom>12][value='450'],[zoom>12][value='550'],[zoom>12][value='650'],[zoom>12][value='750'],[zoom>12][value='850'],[zoom>12][value='950'],[zoom>12][value='1050'],[zoom>12][value='1150'],[zoom>12][value='1250'],[zoom>12][value='1350'],[zoom>12][value='1450'],[zoom>12][value='1550'],[zoom>12][value='1650'],[zoom>12][value='1750'],[zoom>12][value='1850'],[zoom>12][value='1950'],[zoom>12][value='2050'],[zoom>12][value='2150'] {
  line-width: 0.7;
  line-color: #4b3ebc;
  line-opacity: 1;
  text-face-name: 'DejaVu Sans Book';
  text-name: [value];
}
```

I won't post the same CSS expressed the verbose way - if you consider the way those `OR` conditions decompose, clearly it's a lot more repetitive.

(I should note that in fact I use Postman, not cURL, but all the docs talk about cURL, so I thought I'd use the same language here.)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do it would be:

```
    #layer[zoom > 10][value='200'] {  
line-width: 1.5;   
line-color: #4b3ebc;   
line-opacity: 1; 
}



 #layer[zoom > 10][value='300'] {   
line-width: 1.5;   
line-color: #4b3ebc;   
line-opacity: 1; 
}
 etc
```

I'm seeing that according the syntax the values are string types, I would transform them to a numeric type and apply a similar syntax to avoid writing so many conditions:

```
 #layer[zoom > 10][value > 200] {  
    line-width: 1.5;   
    line-color: #4b3ebc;   
    line-opacity: 1; 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Oriol - I realised my question hadn't clearly shown that Builder accepts the more concise syntax (the second code sample) while cURL does not.  I've edited the question now.  Is there a reason for the difference?